# C# Visual Studio Open context menus the other way?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, contextmenu

Normal context menus in Visual Studio always appear right to the mouse after you open them. Is it possible to make the context menu to appear left to the mouse after it opens? So it actually opens from right to left, instead from left to right.

**Hope you know what I mean.** (And no, the text in it is NOT meant, just the way the context menu opens) I wasn't able to find anything on that. It's just for aesthetics btw.

Comment: Are you using Windows 8?

Comment: Actually yes. But it should work with every Windows version of course.

Comment: I think it works like you described on win 8 only.

Comment: http://superuser.com is better place for Windows configuration question...

Answer (score 29):

This is a new ergonomic feature in the Windows. The Windows check if you are using a touch screen than the Menus will open at the left side the reason is the human hand cover the right side of the clicked/pressed area (mouse pointer does not do that).

--------------------------------------------------Update -------------------------------------------------------------

I found the soultion for your prblem :-) you have to select from **Tablet PC Settings** the **Left Handed**, this will solve your problem.

1. Press the Windows logo key+R to bring up the Run dialog box. In the Open line, copy/paste the following text.
2. shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}
3. Press OK.

This will start the Tablet PC Settings configuration dialog (Even if you do not have a Tablet PC).

4. Select the Other Tab.
5. In the Handedness section, place a check mark in the Left Handed option.
6. Click OK.

Look to this information from microsoft:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-application-menus-drop-to-left-instead/2d362701-90e4-4ea6-a3a1-c1391a3d2bea

Do not forget to mark the answer.

Comment: So there is no way to open a context menu that way with a mouse?

Comment: Try this make the mouse for left-handed I hope that Windows todo the rest.                                                          1. (settings) "mouse" → Mouse
2. Select "Switch primary and secondary buttons"     http://superuser.com/questions/537761/how-to-make-mouse-pointers-left-handed-friendly-in-windows-8

Comment: Great, but the context menu should drop left for everyone, not just for users who selected that setting. :/

Comment: You can apply the changes just for the current user mark the answer if your Problem is solved! thanks

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't solve my problem since the application is meant for the general public, not just for me or other users on my computer.

Comment: There is no other workaround for this problem. Microsoft's detection of whether I'm using a tablet or touch screen is dumb. I'm in an AWS WorkSpace--definitely not a touch screen or tablet--freshly installed with Windows 10 21H1, and it still pops up menus to the left. Having to access a secret control panel is horrible UX.